# CSS Grid: Empty Header Columns

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

[This table layout using CSS Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeYeK.jpg)I am new to CSS Grid and would like to know if the following can be achieved using grid layout.

Comment: Yes. Yes, it can. If you share your "*[mcve]*" code we may even be able to show you how, please see the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Yes, you can do it.

You can generate CSS Grid layouts [here](https://grid.layoutit.com/)

I have also generated one for you which would represent current situation.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "empty1 empty1 header1 header2 header3 empty2 empty2" "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text6 text7" "text8 text9 text10 text11 text12 text13 text14";
}

.text1 {
  grid-area: text1;
}

.text2 {
  grid-area: text2;
}

.text3 {
  grid-area: text3;
}

.text4 {
  grid-area: text4;
}

.text5 {
  grid-area: text5;
}

.text6 {
  grid-area: text6;
}

.text7 {
  grid-area: text7;
}

.text14 {
  grid-area: text14;
}

.text13 {
  grid-area: text13;
}

.text12 {
  grid-area: text12;
}

.text11 {
  grid-area: text11;
}

.text10 {
  grid-area: text10;
}

.text9 {
  grid-area: text9;
}

.text8 {
  grid-area: text8;
}

.empty1 {
  grid-area: empty1;
}

.empty2 {
  grid-area: empty2;
}

.header1 {
  grid-area: header1;
}

.header2 {
  grid-area: header2;
}

.header3 {
  grid-area: header3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text1">text1</div>
  <div class="text2">text2</div>
  <div class="text3">text3</div>
  <div class="text4">text4</div>
  <div class="text5">text5</div>
  <div class="text6">text6</div>
  <div class="text7">text7</div>
  <div class="text14">text14</div>
  <div class="text13">text13</div>
  <div class="text12">text12</div>
  <div class="text11">text11</div>
  <div class="text10">text10</div>
  <div class="text9">text9</div>
  <div class="text8">text8</div>
  <div class="empty1"></div>
  <div class="empty2"></div>
  <div class="header1">HDR Item1</div>
  <div class="header2">HDR Item2</div>
  <div class="header3">HDR Item3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @Damian ^_^ .
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. ( +1 )

Comment: I edited your answer to convert your posted code into a runnable stack snippet; hopefully it still works as you intended? If not, you can roll-back the edit or further [edit] the answer to improve or correct it.

Comment: It works. Thank you for the improvement :). I will keep that in mind

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. Can we achieve this without the empty divs. Say I just have hdr1,2,3 and want space before the first one and after the last one.

Comment: I am not sure. The whole idea of a grid is so that there are equal elements that you can merge. However, you could use CSS Flexbox to achieve the same effect but without empty divs. You can read more about the Flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/